# вставка аудио html5

Tags: html5, аудио

Как закрасить аудио, вместо серого, поменять на черный цвет например и убрать округления?

```
<audio class="myaudio" preload="auto" controls>
        <source src="assets/audio.mp3" />
        <source src="assets/audio.ogg" />
        <source src="assets/audio.wav" />
    </audio>
```

Comment: Вид аудиоплеера зависит от конкретного браузера, не проще ли использовать какой-нибудь адаптивный JS-плеер?

Comment: @ГлебШапошников можете скинуть примеры с кодом?

Answer (score 0):

В css файле пропиши audio {
твой код.
}

Comment: я так и делал, только не могу его закрасить, не знаю как видоизменить кнопку `play/pause` и тд. Если уже делали, подскажите как?

Comment: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/ru/tutorials/create-a-customized-html5-audio-player--webdesign-7081